# Проблемы с кодировкой при записи в файл

Tags: python, unicode

При записи текста в файл:

```
open("textsfornn.txt", "a",  encoding='utf8').write(str(categories_list.categories_list[a][1]+" "+ description_item.getText())+"\n\r")
```

В итоговом файле получаю мешанину из следующих символов:

```
Р—Р°РєСѓРїРєР° СЌР»РµРєС‚СЂРёС‡РµСЃРєРёС… С‡Р°Р№РЅРёРєРѕРІ РґР»СЏ Р
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: Для начала проверьте текст, который вы пишите в файл. Потому как ваша "Закупка электрических чайников" отображается так, будто вы сохранили текст в кодировке cp1251.

Comment: у меня есть парсер который скачивает описание с сайта и далее записывает его в файл

Comment: что можно сделать?

Comment: если нужно, могу скинуть код

Comment: Ну таки с этого начинать нужно. Конечно, добавьте код в вопрос. Только отформатируйте его нормально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала проверьте, какая кодировка у вас выставлена. Меняли ли вы кодировку в скрипте вручную (вместо utf-8 по умолчанию). Получаемый вами результат - это строка в кодировке cp1251, записанная в файле с кодировкой utf-8.
То есть, вы открываете файл в кодировке `utg-8`, именно в такой кодировке и нужно записывать данные, а вы отдаете их в `cp1251`.

```
# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-  #<-- вот про эту кодировку речь
s='Закупка электрочайников'
with open("textsfornn.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
   f.write(s)
```

У вас получится как раз то, что вы имеете:

```
Р—Р°РєСѓРїРєР° СЌР»РµРєС‚СЂРѕС‡Р°Р№РЅРёРєРѕРІ
```

Либо уберите аргумент encoding при открытии файла, либо уберите заголовок кодировки в скрипте (если он у вас есть).

Comment: использовал оператор with(), всё заработало, кодировка стала веной